# Job arranger / Job Arranger Manager first settings

Tags: zabbix

I try to configure Job Arranger (JAZ) and try to integrat it with Zabbix, but I am very confused with EN documentation situation.

My environment is:

CentOS 7.6 (Job Arranger server/postgres, Zabbix server)
Windows Server 2016 Std (Job Arranger agent, Zabbix agent, Job Arranger Manager)

I configured JAZ server and agent according to official documentation (JAP) in combination with https://mastering-jaz.github.io

Everything look perfect, JAZ server, JAZ agent and JAZ Manager work, but when I make ODBC configuration and run JAZ manager, they ask me for credentials to job controller. I don't have any idea which credential JAZ manager wants. Everywhere I try to looking for right settings, I don't have luck.

Comment: I'm not sure how does Zabbix come into play here, could you please clarify? Or is it that you intend to do something with Zabbix, but are not getting that far yet?

Comment: @Richlv, thanks for your comment. JAZ is third-party tool for zabbix. I tagged my question with zabbix tag, because server fault grant me us only existing tags. I'm sorry I used an inaccurate tag for you.

Comment: Oh, I see - then the tags likely makes sense, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Zabbix Server login credentials.